# Heroku and Procfile `Release:` with no dynos

Tags: heroku

This is from my Heroku application resource page:

[image]

In my `procfile` I have the following line:

```
release: python manage.py migrate
```

Upon deployment **it executes just fine**. I can see it working. However, I'm puzzled as the "Release" is configured to have 0 dynos/$0.00/month. It is possible to configure it to have more dynos at a cost, but It seems like it's not necessary in order to run it.

What bears the expense of running the release process? Is it safe to keep it at 0 dynos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's safe to keep it at 0 dynos, as your `release` script will be running on a [one-off dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos). As such; they only run on demand, and are charged at the same rate as regular dynos, pro-rated to the second.

The Heroku documentation is also quite comprehensive on [when your release task will run](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile).